# Lookup child rows in a single DataFrame without using loops

Tags: python, pandas, data-analysis

Currently I'm trying to extract meaninful data from a ticket system (Redmine). One of my tasks hereof is to find **all** the child tickets from a list of tickets which interest me. Since the children are of the same shape as their parents, live in the same DataFrame - so I cannot use `pd.merge`, and furthermore the child could have children themselves, I first tried to find them recursively, but fairly quickly stumbled over

> maximum recursion depth exceeded error

So my next approach was to serialize the procedure instead. Unfortunately that makes me lookup such tickets multiple times in nested loops, which really is too slow for my needs.
So to not further overwork your imagination here's a possible example of data I'm working on:

```
            id  project.id  status.id  priority.id  author.id  assigned_to.id  parent.id  category.id
    0    18543          18          5            2         85            85.0    18203.0          NaN
    1    18542          18          5            2         85            85.0    18538.0          NaN
    2    18541          71          5            2         67            67.0    17788.0          NaN
    3    18540          18          5            3        105            85.0        NaN        150.0
    4    18539          17          5            2         81            81.0    18537.0          NaN
    ..     ...         ...        ...          ...        ...             ...        ...          ...
    806  18257           4          1            2          3             NaN    16423.0          NaN
    807  17738          11          1            2          3             NaN    17737.0          NaN
    808  16017          65          2            2         81             NaN        NaN          NaN
    809   2473          65         15            2          4             4.0        NaN          NaN
    810  16423          65         18            2          3            18.0        NaN          NaN

    [811 rows x 8 columns]
```

Think of it as a hierarchical tree structure. As you can see, it would be quite easy to work bottom-up through the `parent.id` field, which matches the `id` field of its parent, but to traverse the thing top-down, is not that straight forward.

A solution I came up with is this:

```
def findChildren(issueId, issueFrame):
    # clean data
    safeElements = issueFrame.fillna(0)
    children = safeElements[safeElements['parent.id'] == issueId]
    childList = np.array(children['id'])
    listLength = 0
    # seek until list of children does not grow anymore
    while listLength != len(childList):
        listLength = len(childList)
        for identifier in childList:
            children = safeElements[safeElements['parent.id'] == identifier]
            addToList = np.array(children['id'])
            childList = np.append(childList, addToList)
        childList = np.unique(childList)
    return childList
```

It works! But since I not just have to look for a single issue it takes literally minutes to create me all that lists of children I want. What would be a faster approach? The result doesn't need to be in a list of children. I would also be happy with a filtered DataFrame which holds the rows of its children to the last of their great-great-and-so-on-grandchildren.

Comment: Are you storing the ids as floats and ints?

Comment: @AMC The DataFrame is created by ```pd.io.json.json_normalize```. And since there are NaN values in the ```parent.id``` column (for root issues), these values are float, even though their IDs would be integers otherwise. That's typical in pandas or numpy for lists with missing values. Why?

Comment: _this values are float, even though their IDs would be integers otherwise._ I was asking because I think they should probably be strings. _That's typical in pandas or numpy for lists with missing values. Why?_ IIUC It's not purely about missing values, it's because the elements of both Pandas Series and basic Numpy ndarrays must all have the same type, which leads to things like `object` being chosen since it's the only type they have in common. Which version of Pandas are you using, by the way?

Comment: @AMC I use 0.25 or 1.0.1, depending on the system I use. You are correct regarding that all values in a list have to be of the same type. But since None is not a valid integer, and all of those values were read as numbers (from json), Pandas converted them into floats to mark missing values as NaN. That didn't give me any problems so far.

Comment: _That didn't give me any problems so far._ Eh, I see no reason not to use the appropriate type, it's an easy way of mitigating potential problems. Regarding the versions you're using, there is currently work being done on revamping dtypes in Pandas, including [nullable integers](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/user_guide/integer_na.html), for example.

Comment: The correct type for the ID is int. I cannot use int until I took care about missing values. I did not chose the value type of the columns myself, and as long as such a feature is purely experimental, I think it is responsible of Pandas not to enforce it in its normalizing function. So what are you suggesting? Would the loops run faster if there would be object or experimental arrays used instead? Because AFAIR the Python loops are slow even on np.array with a single, proper type.

Comment: _The correct type for the ID is int._ How come? Isn't the ID a value used to identify the ticket? _Would the loops run faster if there would be object or experimental arrays used instead?_ Eh, I can't see it making a difference. The big improvement would be to use Pandas/NumPy vectorized methods, instead of Python loops, which can be a bit more difficult to implement.

Comment: _Eh, I can't see it making a difference._ Exactly! _The big improvement would be to use Pandas/NumPy vectorized methods, instead of Python loops, which can be a bit more difficult to implement._ That's why I asked that question about how to implement it without loops.

Comment: How about this: Have a list of tickets, and an empty list to hold their parents. For each ticket, add their parent to the other list. Once you're done, empty the current ticket list, and swap the two. Hope my explanation is clear, it's to put into so few words.

Comment: I'm not sure if I get your point. Even if I use fancy indexing I have to loop over every level/dimension of the tree. _For each ticket_ sounds like a loop. Wouldn't it be even less effective? Right now I match several children at once. If I go bottom-up I only hit a single parent for each ticket.

Comment: Never mind, you were already using the pattern I suggested, for some reason I confused this question with another one and thought you were using recursion....

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The biggest performance bottleneck in your code is array-matching. Searching an array is an `O(n)` operation. Repeat it for each element in another array makes the operation `O(n*m)`. For faster result, lookup a dictionary instead, whose look up time is always `O(1)`.

And there is a way to do it without recursion. Try this:

```
def findChildren(issueId, issueFrame, cache=None):
    # Create a dictionary which lists all children an `id` has
    # The result is something like this:
    # {
    #   1: [2,3,4], # 1 has children 2, 3, 4
    #   2: [5]      # 2 has child 5
    # }
    _cache = cache or issueFrame[['parent.id', 'id']].groupby('parent.id')['id'].apply(list).to_dict()

    # We start with the supplied `issueId`
    check_list = [issueId]

    # The final list of children
    ids = []

    while len(check_list) > 0:
        parent_id = check_list.pop()

        # Get all children of the current `parent_id`...
        children = _cache.get(parent_id, [])

        # ... then check if they have an children too
        check_list += children

        # and add them to the list of children for the current ticket
        ids += children

    # Finally, extract those children from the DataFrame
    return issueFrame[issueFrame['id'].isin(ids)]
```

Comment: Hello, and thanks for your reply. I tested this with a lookup search in an original frame of 4344 rows, expecting 79 results. While the result had no errors, the performance is the same as with my code. We speak about 75ms of your solution vs. 76ms of my solution. And while your answer regarding time complexity is true in general, object evaluation in dictionaries in that while loop may have such a huge overhead, that it almost nullifies the improvement. I will dig deeper into the groupby approach, nevertheless.

Comment: If your intention is to find the trees for all parent.ids, there may be a more efficient approach than looping trough each parent.id. Would you mind sharing your input so I can think more about it. Only two columns are needed: id and parent.id

Comment: Unfortunately I can't. I also don't need all trees. But to create the cache just once for the DataFrame, which is pretty static in my problem, and add it as a third parameter, decreases the execution time by one magnitude. Instead of 17 seconds I need only 2 seconds, if I search for every child of one category/author/tracker. If you don't mind  to change your answer in that way or let me do it, I'd accept your answer. It really pointed me into the right direction. One question though: is the `.to_dict()` part neccessary? I didn't used it.

Comment: That was the first thing on my mind for the rework. You got there before me. I was not aware that there was a `Series.get` so `to_dict` may not be necessary. Updated my answer